# How can I setup simple audio player with background and notification support in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am using [Flutter sound package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) to play a single audio from a URL and also show notification media controller.
I have tried the demo app on their documentation but its not clear to understand.
The background audio player somehow worked fine but I want to remove the recording system and make it to play audio from URL

[Here is the demo app](https://github.com/Canardoux/tau/tree/master/flutter_sound/example/lib/demo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example of the how to do the above question.
you will have many errors if you haven't enabled null safety which is just changing  your flutter sdk in the Pub.yaml

```
 environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

to the following if you are using flutter above 2.12 otherwise check on how to migrate flutter project to null safety

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:math';
    
    import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
    import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
    

    late AudioHandler _audioHandler;
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      _audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
        builder: () => AudioPlayerHandler(),
        config: const AudioServiceConfig(
          androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.myaudio.channel',
          androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
          androidNotificationOngoing: true,
        ),
      );
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Audio Service Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
          home: MainScreen(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Audio Service Demo'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                // Show media item title
                StreamBuilder<MediaItem?>(
                  stream: _audioHandler.mediaItem,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final mediaItem = snapshot.data;
                    return Text(mediaItem?.title ?? '');
                  },
                ),
                // Play/pause/stop buttons.
                StreamBuilder<bool>(
                  stream: _audioHandler.playbackState
                      .map((state) => state.playing)
                      .distinct(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final playing = snapshot.data ?? false;
                    return Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        _button(Icons.fast_rewind, _audioHandler.rewind),
                        if (playing)
                          _button(Icons.pause, _audioHandler.pause)
                        else
                          _button(Icons.play_arrow, _audioHandler.play),
                        _button(Icons.stop, _audioHandler.stop),
                        _button(Icons.fast_forward, _audioHandler.fastForward),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
                // A seek bar.
                StreamBuilder<MediaState>(
                  stream: _mediaStateStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final mediaState = snapshot.data;
                    return SeekBar(
                      duration: mediaState?.mediaItem?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                      position: mediaState?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                      onChangeEnd: (newPosition) {
                        _audioHandler.seek(newPosition);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
                // Display the processing state.
                StreamBuilder<AudioProcessingState>(
                  stream: _audioHandler.playbackState
                      .map((state) => state.processingState)
                      .distinct(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final processingState =
                        snapshot.data ?? AudioProcessingState.idle;
                    return Text(
                        "Processing state: ${describeEnum(processingState)}");
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      /// A stream reporting the combined state of the current media item and its
      /// current position.
      Stream<MediaState> get _mediaStateStream =>
          Rx.combineLatest2<MediaItem?, Duration, MediaState>(
              _audioHandler.mediaItem,
              AudioService.position,
                  (mediaItem, position) => MediaState(mediaItem, position));
    
      IconButton _button(IconData iconData, VoidCallback onPressed) => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(iconData),
        iconSize: 64.0,
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );
    }
    
    class MediaState {
      final MediaItem? mediaItem;
      final Duration position;
    
      MediaState(this.mediaItem, this.position);
    }
    
    /// An [AudioHandler] for playing a single item.
    class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with SeekHandler {
      static final _item = MediaItem(
        id: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3',
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            'https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
      );
    
      final _player = AudioPlayer();
    
      /// Initialise our audio handler.
      AudioPlayerHandler() {
        // what state to display, here we set up our audio handler to broadcast all
        // playback state changes as they happen via playbackState...
        _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
        // ... and also the current media item via mediaItem.
        mediaItem.add(_item);
        // Load the player.
        _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(_item.id)));
      }
    
      // In this simple example, we handle only 4 actions: play, pause, seek and
      // stop. Any button press from the Flutter UI, notification, lock screen or
      // headset will be routed through to these 4 methods so that you can handle
      // your audio playback logic in one place.
    
      @override
      Future<void> play() => _player.play();
    
      @override
      Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();
    
      @override
      Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);
    
      @override
      Future<void> stop() => _player.stop();
    
      /// Transform a just_audio event into an audio_service state.
      ///
      /// This method is used from the constructor. Every event received from the
      /// just_audio player will be transformed into an audio_service state so that
      /// it can be broadcast to audio_service clients.
      PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
        return PlaybackState(
          controls: [
            MediaControl.rewind,
            if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
            MediaControl.stop,
            MediaControl.fastForward,
          ],
          systemActions: const {
            MediaAction.seek,
            MediaAction.seekForward,
            MediaAction.seekBackward,
          },
          androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
          processingState: const {
            ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
            ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
            ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
            ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
            ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
          }[_player.processingState]!,
          playing: _player.playing,
          updatePosition: _player.position,
          bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
          speed: _player.speed,
          queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    class PositionData {
      final Duration position;
      final Duration bufferedPosition;
      final Duration duration;
    
      PositionData(this.position, this.bufferedPosition, this.duration);
    }
    
    class SeekBar extends StatefulWidget {
      final Duration duration;
      final Duration position;
      final Duration bufferedPosition;
      final ValueChanged<Duration>? onChanged;
      final ValueChanged<Duration>? onChangeEnd;
    
      SeekBar({
        required this.duration,
        required this.position,
        this.bufferedPosition = Duration.zero,
        this.onChanged,
        this.onChangeEnd,
      });
    
      @override
      _SeekBarState createState() => _SeekBarState();
    }
    
    class _SeekBarState extends State<SeekBar> {
      double? _dragValue;
      bool _dragging = false;
      late SliderThemeData _sliderThemeData;
    
      @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
    
        _sliderThemeData = SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          trackHeight: 2.0,
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final value = min(
          _dragValue ?? widget.position.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
          widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
        );
        if (_dragValue != null && !_dragging) {
          _dragValue = null;
        }
        return Stack(
          children: [
            SliderTheme(
              data: _sliderThemeData.copyWith(
                thumbShape: HiddenThumbComponentShape(),
                activeTrackColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
                inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
              ),
              child: ExcludeSemantics(
                child: Slider(
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                  value: min(widget.bufferedPosition.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                      widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()),
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliderTheme(
              data: _sliderThemeData.copyWith(
                inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              child: Slider(
                min: 0.0,
                max: widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                value: value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  if (!_dragging) {
                    _dragging = true;
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    _dragValue = value;
                  });
                  if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                    widget.onChanged!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                  }
                },
                onChangeEnd: (value) {
                  if (widget.onChangeEnd != null) {
                    widget.onChangeEnd!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                  }
                  _dragging = false;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 16.0,
              bottom: 0.0,
              child: Text(
                  RegExp(r'((^0*[1-9]\d*:)?\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+$')
                      .firstMatch("$_remaining")
                      ?.group(1) ??
                      '$_remaining',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Duration get _remaining => widget.duration - widget.position;
    }
    
    class HiddenThumbComponentShape extends SliderComponentShape {
      @override
      Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) => Size.zero;
    
      @override
      void paint(
          PaintingContext context,
          Offset center, {
            required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
            required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
            required bool isDiscrete,
            required TextPainter labelPainter,
            required RenderBox parentBox,
            required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
            required TextDirection textDirection,
            required double value,
            required double textScaleFactor,
            required Size sizeWithOverflow,
          }) {}
    }
    
    class LoggingAudioHandler extends CompositeAudioHandler {
      LoggingAudioHandler(AudioHandler inner) : super(inner) {
        playbackState.listen((state) {
          _log('playbackState changed: $state');
        });
        queue.listen((queue) {
          _log('queue changed: $queue');
        });
        queueTitle.listen((queueTitle) {
          _log('queueTitle changed: $queueTitle');
        });
        mediaItem.listen((mediaItem) {
          _log('mediaItem changed: $mediaItem');
        });
        ratingStyle.listen((ratingStyle) {
          _log('ratingStyle changed: $ratingStyle');
        });
        androidPlaybackInfo.listen((androidPlaybackInfo) {
          _log('androidPlaybackInfo changed: $androidPlaybackInfo');
        });
        customEvent.listen((dynamic customEventStream) {
          _log('customEvent changed: $customEventStream');
        });
        customState.listen((dynamic customState) {
          _log('customState changed: $customState');
        });
      }
    
      // TODO: Use logger. Use different log levels.
      void _log(String s) => print('----- LOG: $s');
    
      @override
      Future<void> prepare() {
        _log('prepare()');
        return super.prepare();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> prepareFromMediaId(String mediaId,
          [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('prepareFromMediaId($mediaId, $extras)');
        return super.prepareFromMediaId(mediaId, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> prepareFromSearch(String query, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('prepareFromSearch($query, $extras)');
        return super.prepareFromSearch(query, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> prepareFromUri(Uri uri, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('prepareFromSearch($uri, $extras)');
        return super.prepareFromUri(uri, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> play() {
        _log('play()');
        return super.play();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> playFromMediaId(String mediaId, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('playFromMediaId($mediaId, $extras)');
        return super.playFromMediaId(mediaId, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> playFromSearch(String query, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('playFromSearch($query, $extras)');
        return super.playFromSearch(query, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> playFromUri(Uri uri, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('playFromUri($uri, $extras)');
        return super.playFromUri(uri, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> playMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) {
        _log('playMediaItem($mediaItem)');
        return super.playMediaItem(mediaItem);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> pause() {
        _log('pause()');
        return super.pause();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> click([MediaButton button = MediaButton.media]) {
        _log('click($button)');
        return super.click(button);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> stop() {
        _log('stop()');
        return super.stop();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> addQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) {
        _log('addQueueItem($mediaItem)');
        return super.addQueueItem(mediaItem);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) {
        _log('addQueueItems($mediaItems)');
        return super.addQueueItems(mediaItems);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> insertQueueItem(int index, MediaItem mediaItem) {
        _log('insertQueueItem($index, $mediaItem)');
        return super.insertQueueItem(index, mediaItem);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> updateQueue(List<MediaItem> queue) {
        _log('updateQueue($queue)');
        return super.updateQueue(queue);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> updateMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) {
        _log('updateMediaItem($mediaItem)');
        return super.updateMediaItem(mediaItem);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> removeQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) {
        _log('removeQueueItem($mediaItem)');
        return super.removeQueueItem(mediaItem);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> removeQueueItemAt(int index) {
        _log('removeQueueItemAt($index)');
        return super.removeQueueItemAt(index);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> skipToNext() {
        _log('skipToNext()');
        return super.skipToNext();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> skipToPrevious() {
        _log('skipToPrevious()');
        return super.skipToPrevious();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> fastForward() {
        _log('fastForward()');
        return super.fastForward();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> rewind() {
        _log('rewind()');
        return super.rewind();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) {
        _log('skipToQueueItem($index)');
        return super.skipToQueueItem(index);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> seek(Duration position) {
        _log('seek($position)');
        return super.seek(position);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> setRating(Rating rating, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) {
        _log('setRating($rating, $extras)');
        return super.setRating(rating, extras);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> setCaptioningEnabled(bool enabled) {
        _log('setCaptioningEnabled($enabled)');
        return super.setCaptioningEnabled(enabled);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode repeatMode) {
        _log('setRepeatMode($repeatMode)');
        return super.setRepeatMode(repeatMode);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode shuffleMode) {
        _log('setShuffleMode($shuffleMode)');
        return super.setShuffleMode(shuffleMode);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> seekBackward(bool begin) {
        _log('seekBackward($begin)');
        return super.seekBackward(begin);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> seekForward(bool begin) {
        _log('seekForward($begin)');
        return super.seekForward(begin);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> setSpeed(double speed) {
        _log('setSpeed($speed)');
        return super.setSpeed(speed);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<dynamic> customAction(String name,
          [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
        _log('customAction($name, extras)');
        final dynamic result = await super.customAction(name, extras);
        _log('customAction -> $result');
        return result;
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> onTaskRemoved() {
        _log('onTaskRemoved()');
        return super.onTaskRemoved();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> onNotificationDeleted() {
        _log('onNotificationDeleted()');
        return super.onNotificationDeleted();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<List<MediaItem>> getChildren(String parentMediaId,
          [Map<String, dynamic>? options]) async {
        _log('getChildren($parentMediaId, $options)');
        final result = await super.getChildren(parentMediaId, options);
        _log('getChildren -> $result');
        return result;
      }
    
      @override
      ValueStream<Map<String, dynamic>> subscribeToChildren(String parentMediaId) {
        _log('subscribeToChildren($parentMediaId)');
        final result = super.subscribeToChildren(parentMediaId);
        result.listen((options) {
          _log('$parentMediaId children changed with options $options');
        });
        return result;
      }
    
      @override
      Future<MediaItem?> getMediaItem(String mediaId) async {
        _log('getMediaItem($mediaId)');
        final result = await super.getMediaItem(mediaId);
        _log('getMediaItem -> $result');
        return result;
      }
    
      @override
      Future<List<MediaItem>> search(String query,
          [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
        _log('search($query, $extras)');
        final result = await super.search(query, extras);
        _log('search -> $result');
        return result;
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> androidSetRemoteVolume(int volumeIndex) {
        _log('androidSetRemoteVolume($volumeIndex)');
        return super.androidSetRemoteVolume(volumeIndex);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> androidAdjustRemoteVolume(AndroidVolumeDirection direction) {
        _log('androidAdjustRemoteVolume($direction)');
        return super.androidAdjustRemoteVolume(direction);
      }
    }
    
    void showSliderDialog({
      required BuildContext context,
      required String title,
      required int divisions,
      required double min,
      required double max,
      String valueSuffix = '',
      // TODO: Replace these two by ValueStream.
      required double value,
      required Stream<double> stream,
      required ValueChanged<double> onChanged,
    }) {
      showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          content: StreamBuilder<double>(
            stream: stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) => Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('${snapshot.data?.toStringAsFixed(1)}$valueSuffix',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Fixed',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24.0)),
                  Slider(
                    divisions: divisions,
                    min: min,
                    max: max,
                    value: snapshot.data ?? value,
                    onChanged: onChanged,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Is it serious? All that code to a simple audio player?

Comment: @Fransi Tsena I modify your code by adding 2 audios to be played at the same time, but when I would like to pause both of them, I don't know how to do that.. it is only success when I pause one audio from background

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) with [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service).

As the plugin name says just_audio is just for audio and to create notification you have to use audio_service.

Comment: ok can you give me an example on how to use the package to play music from url with notification

Comment: The [example](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/master/audio_service/example/lib/main.dart) of audio_service does exactly what you are asking for. If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept the answer for further references :)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way for displaying music notifications or any audio file, use the Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer package here is the link to their GitHub and documentation  [link to dicumentation](https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer)